# Sci-fi book featuring insectoid aliens that had biological ships

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I only remember one scene from the book, possibly two. What I remember of it is that the main bad guys were these insectoid aliens that had biological ships and other such things.

The scene that I remember most vividly is where the main characters are stuck on a bug planet running through trying to destroy something, and have to escape in a ship.

I *think* that there was something to do with centaur-like aliens as well that took the main characters from Earth, but I cannot remember exactly.

Comment: I don't remember a book taking place on a bug planet but... Insectoid aliens? Centaur-like aliens? Spaceships? Does [_Animorphs_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animorphs) ring a bell?

Comment: Especially, the book [_The Andalite Chronicles_](http://animorphs.wikia.com/wiki/The_Andalite_Chronicles) had a part on the Taxxon homeworld. Taxxons are like centipedes. Only, you know, bigger (way bigger) and badder.

Comment: [Starship Troopers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers)? There are no centaurs, but they do wear battle armor.

Comment: There are centaur like creatures in a Heinlein novel - I think it’s *Starman Jones*. The one where they get lost on the other side of a space warp point and try to settle the planet but centaurs kidnap some of them so they leave and decide they have to find their way home to earth. No insect like aliens though.

Comment: Sounds like Tyrannids in Warhammer 40k.

Answer (score 3):

To me this sounds like the Khleevi (big cockroach aliens that communicate by clicking) from the Acorna books by Anne McCaffrey...one of the later stories features the heroes visiting a bug homeworld, and the Ancestors of Acorna’s people are sort of like Centaurs.